# Kubuntu 20.04 boot failure on Lenovo Flex-14API 81SS with AMD Ryzen 5 3500U

Tags: boot, kubuntu, 20.04

Title almost says it all. All is well when the laptop is plugged in but fails to boot when running on battery power. After selecting Ubuntu in the Grub menu the laptop never gets to the login screen and freezes with a black screen. Sometimes I see a screen full of garbage and then a frozen black screen. Fans running full speed. I use acpi=off in Grub because without it, the machine won't even boot when plugged in.

This is a dual boot system and Windows 10 boots and works just fine.

Comment: Check for Lenovo firmware updates, and with the latest, you can probably get rid of the acpi=off.  Then things should be better.

Comment: Turn off fastboot in Bios if you can.  Sometimes that can mess things up as well.  Lots and lots of Lenovo power/sleep/suspend/battery issues on this forum.

Comment: The latest BIOS is installed and fastboot is disabled.

Comment: Have you tried asking Lenovo support? They've recently said they'll support Linux much more than they did in the past.

Comment: Can you post a link to a Lenovo site that makes this claim? The laptop did not come with Linux preinstalled. I don't think this is their problem. Is there anyone else out there with similar problems?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on lenovo ideapad 3, ryzen 5 3500u.

Update: Edit grub file as posted in here (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2446942&s=fa07a5f466ffbb54f6148340eb1abb39&p=13971767#post13971767), and solve the problem. I restart the laptop several times and seems to work.

Edit grub:

```
sudo nano /etc/defaut/grub
```

Change line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="iommu=soft quiet splash"
```

then update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue (sorry but i can't post comment) only on HP 255 G7 with Ryzen 5 3500U. dmesg shows that driver is not loading properly when on battery. The PC actually boots to OS, but desktop is not displaying correctly. I can switch to console and back normally. looks to me it's a driver or OS issue.
I can boot with charger in and then i can unplug the charger and behaviour on battery (so far) is normal.